# I want to print counting from 1 onwards using setInterval function of JavaScript but it's giving the output as 0 continuously.

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print counting from 1 onwards using setInterval function of JavaScript but it's giving the output as 0 continuously.

My code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>  //javascript starts
     var x=0;
     function f(){
          document.write(x);
          x++;
     }
     setInterval(f,500); //need to output as 0 then 1 and so on.
</script>//javascript ends
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please check this <html>
<body>
<script>
var x=0;
function f()
{
document.write(x);
x++;
}
setInterval(f,500);
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I know you are new but you should spend some time writing your question properly. It's JavaScript, not jAVASCRIPT.

Comment: Initialise the variable `x`  by 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I m new... Please cooperate

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/7vquztks/2/

```js
var x = 1;

setInterval(function(){
 document.write(x);
  x++;
}, 500);
```

Comment: This produces exactly the same result as the OP's code.

Comment: My code is working fine in Google Chrome but in Mozilla Firefox it is printing just 0...@shiladitya

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works as is, you just need to ensure that you are handling the result properly.

Right now, you are using `document.write()` to output, which means you are having all the numbers display one next to another. You can use a `<p>` tag with a specified id to replace every time instead, so it only displays one number at a time!

That code could look like:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>  //javascript starts
     var x=0;
     function f(){
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
          x++;
     }
     setInterval(f,500); //need to output as 0 then 1 and so on.
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqoau8zb/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: If this helped, consider accepting this answer! Thanks!